# WordPress E-Commerce Plugins

Tags: wordpress

Please suggest me some better ecommerce plugins for WordPress sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [WP-ecommerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) if you're looking for a shopping cart. And Your Member ( www.newmedias.co.uk/wordpress-membership) is ok if you're trying to do content subscription (ie pay x for access to content in the blog)

Comment: Be warned that at this time the wp-e-commerce plugin has many bugs, and you will likely be disappointed by the lack of a support community.

Comment: @Will Sheppard I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I can heartily recommend [Shopp from Ingenesis Limited](http://shopplugin.net/) if you want a customisable solution. I have used it for 6 sites now, some very customised, and - although I've hit problems as you would with any development work - nothing has been insurmountable. This is mainly because the Shopp page template and Plugin API are so versatile. Support is good, although you have to get your hands dirty and try and work along with the developers to get things working i.e. they usually won't just write a custom Payment gateway or shipping plugin for you!

One drawback is that I can't link you to any of the API docs because they operate a 'buy, try, no quibble money back thing instead' of a trial, and only allow registered users to see all the docs. There is a [Feature List](https://shopplugin.net/features/) here though.

Comment: Documentation/API is available to all now, https://shopplugin.net/api/

Answer (score 0):

[wp e-commerce](http://getshopped.org/) - free version available, has addons and themes

[shopp](https://shopplugin.net/) - paid

Comment: Shopp is open source software. You only pay for support when you need it.